# OpenCV 3.0 missing methods like drawMatches and drawMatchesKNN

Tags: python, opencv, keypoint

I've recently updated to OpenCV 3.0 tp2 on Python(2.7), to avail of the methods like drawMatches and drawMatchesKnn(), but neither seem to be available. I built from source, and everything installed correctly, but I still don't have the methods.

I had OpenCV 2.4.8, and I know it didn't have the methods, but I was pretty sure the 3.0tp2 did have them. Have they been removed since? Or have the names changed since?

Has anyone got an idea on what I could do to resolve this?

Comment: what is tp2 ? as of 3.0 , it [seems they are in](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/include/opencv2/features2d.hpp#L1442) while [2.4 only has drawKeypoints](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/features2d/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp#L1515) [the CV_EXPORTS_W or CV_EXPORTS_AS will make it wrap into python/java/matlab]

Comment: I got it from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.0-ocl-tech-preview/

Which is the link provided in the OpenCV documentation.

Comment: oh, did not know, that there were 3.0 binaries even, thanks for the info ;)  but yes, probably building from src (you will need cmake for this) will resolve your problem

Comment: cloning the repo using git will have the additional advantage, that later updates (git pull) are only a tiny fraction of the codebase, like a couple mb only

Comment: I used CMake to do it, and I've just seen that I've got features2d.hpp. The methods are in the HPP file.

I built it with cmake and visual studio(running all_build and then install), so I'm a little lost as to why I can see the methods but they're not implemented in python.

Comment: I'm going to rebuild it in visual studio, and see if that solves it.

Comment: in fact, the python api is *generated* from the c++ headers. when building, you'll see pyopencv_generated_funcs.h and similar in build/modules/python. after the build finishes, you run the INSTALL project, which will copy the cv2.pyd to your python folder

Comment: compile it from source. The functions are available.

Comment: Just compiled it from source, using the master branch from Itzeez. Ran the cmake,and then ran the opencv.sln (allbuild followed by install), and it ran successfully.
The functions aren't there though. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current official release of OpenCV is 2.4.8, and 2.4.9 is probably going to be released soon. OpenCV 3.0 is still under development, and might have some missing features or bugs.

I'd recommend to check if functionalities You are looking for are available in the [current release](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/refman.html), and if they aren't, check if Your problem is not listed as todos for 3.0 [here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/roadmap).

To get current release just do git checkout 2.4.8 from Your root source directory.

Comment: Found out what the problem was last night. Python27 could see the updated version of cv2, including the methods I needed, but PyDev(in Eclipse) couldn't. Refreshed my IDE's settings, and it worked fine.